# how to get the HWND from HMENU?

Tags: windows, user-interface

the MSDN says, the menu is actually a window withe window class "#32768", so how can i get the hwnd from hmenu?

Comment: I have to ask: what are you planning to do with the menu window? Is it in your process or some other process? Could you use owner-draw or bitmap menu items instead?

Comment: I want create a window, which can show beyond the parent, and also keep the parent active. just like the combobox dropdown window. so i try to use the menu window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the `FindWindow(...)` or `FindWindowEx(...)` API methods.

Comment: FindWindow handles only top level windows, but FindWindowEx allows to search child window